# If field_1 contains %word% return field_2 with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that unfortunately happens to be filled like this:

```
id       field_1       field_2
-------- ------------- -------
1        weight        175
1        height        88
1        age           26
2        weight        166
2        age           15
3        weight        84
3        height        188
3        age           44
```

Let's assume I want to get the `height` and `age` data from id 3.

I'm making a `SELECT` query and `GROUP BY id`, but what do I do next?

I tried this method:

```
if (strpos( $row['field_1'], 'height') !== false) :
    $height = $row['field_2'];
endif;
```

but it seems to be a bad option because it acts weird when there are many variables involved.

Comment: Show your query. If you're getting all the rows for id=1, you shouldn't be grouping.

Comment: Why are you using `strpos` instead of just `if ($row['field_1'] == 'height')`?

Comment: @Barmar you are correct, GROUP BY did ruin it after all. I want all the rows, not just the first one. And for the `strpos`, I use it because sometimes the field contains additional words. Like `the height`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the results in one row, do two `SELECT`s and select the results from each:

```
SELECT height, age FROM (
  ( SELECT `field_2` AS height FROM tbl WHERE `id`=1 AND `field_1`='height') t1,
  ( SELECT `field_2` AS age FROM tbl WHERE `id`=1 AND `field_1`='age') t2
)
```

Alternately, if you don't mind parsing through the results:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE id=3 AND ( field_1='height' OR field_2='age' )
```

Then your PHP code will have to check each row for `height` or `age`:

```
if ( $row['field_1'] == 'age' ) {
    // $row['field_2'] is the age
} else if ( $row['field_2' == 'height' ) {
    // $row['field_2'] is the height
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I prefer the second option. But I'm still having a problem -- I'm getting the result twice. So I'm getting one row of results for the `height` and one row for the `age`. How can I limit results so it would somehow group all the data into one array or string? I'm using `while` to loop through the results.

Comment: The problem is, the database is really big and there are many variables in play, so rows are repeating for each unique `field_1`. And I would want it to group by id.

Comment: Why do you prefer the second option if the first option gives you exactly what you want: one row with the height and age for a given `id`?

Comment: Because it does not return one row either. The real database is more complex and I'm selecting rows by the third field. The third field is limiting the query to a few id's, but not to  a single one, sadly.

Comment: Oh, I'm almost there! Can you please tell me how to select other fields as well in your first query? Like if I want to request `field_3`.

Comment: What is contained in `field_3` and what condition should select it? In my first example, after `t2`, add a comma and then on the next line: `( SELECT field_3 AS weight FROM tbl WHERE id=1 AND field_1='weight') t3`. You'll also have to change the first `SELECT height, age` to `SELECT height, age, weight`. Of course, I'm assuming `field_3` contains weight, which might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$arr = [];
$height;
$width;
$q = "SELECT `field_2` FROM 
`table_Nam` WHERE `id` = 3";
$result = 
mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query
($con, $q));

while($row = $result){
    if($row['field_1'] == 
    'height')  
    {
   $height = $row['field_2'];
    }else if($row[field_2'] == 
    'age'){
      $age = $row['field_2'];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps